# Copy & Paste of code won't copy the data validation formatting from the cell I'm copying

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy & paste data with VBA and to maintain the data validation in the cell, but my code is giving me errors.

Here is what I have

```
Sheets("INITIAL").Activate
Range("aa8:ah8").Copy
Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Activate
Range("aa8:ah8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

`Paste:=xlPasteValidation` is giving errors; I tried removing "Paste:" which repeats and "Pastevalidation" to "DataVAlidation" without success.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

```
Sheets("INITIAL").Range("aa8:ah8").Copy

With Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("aa8:ah8")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End with
```

Comment: Hello Tim thank you for taking the time. I chagend the code as below:

'    Sheets("INITIAL").Activate
    Range("D15:AA22").Copy
With Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("d15:aa22")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With'

It now says merged cells should have the same size, can it only paste the values ignoring if merged or not?

Answer (score 0):

Shortening this up... copy/paste with a data validation table will A) keep the value and B) keep the data validation:

```
Sheets("INITIAL").Range("aa8:ah8").Copy Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("aa8:ah8")
```

Just in one line of code for you.

---

If you just want values, no data validation tables:

```
Sheets("SERVICES BREAKDOWN").Range("aa8:ah8").value = Sheets("INITIAL").Range("aa8:ah8").value
```